# Is it a correct interrogative sentence?

Tags: grammaire, questions, pronom-de-reprise

My book gives these sentences:

> Où Michel fait-il ses études?
>
> Que fait Michel après les cours?

Why is the second one just a subject-object switch without this **-il** postfix? For me it should be:

> Que Michel fait-il après les cours?

Comment: The _pronom de reprise_ is correct here, but more often than not it is not used.  Usage increase with the complexity of the subject to eventually become mandatory.

Comment: @Unfrancophone: Is my sentence (the last) grammatically correct?

Comment: yes, just less common than inversion with such a simple subject as _Michel_.